# Why do I get a larger relative speedup vs. scalar from SIMD intrinsics with larger arrays?

Tags: c++, performance, simd, avx, microbenchmark

I want to learn SIMD programming. Now I have some interesting moment in my code.

I just want to measure the time of work of my code. I try to apply some base function for my array with a particular size.

Firstly I try to use function that was written with SIMD instructions and after that I try to use usual aproach. And I compare time of this two realizations the same function.

I defined performance like (time without sse) / (time using sse).

But when my size is 8 , I have performance is 1.3,  and when my size = 512 - I have Performance = 3, if I have size = 1000 performance = 4, if size = 4000 -> performance = 5.

I don't understand why my performance is increasing when size of array is increasing.

My code

```
void init(double* v, size_t size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        v[i] = i / 10.0;
    }
}

void sub_func_sse(double* v, int start_idx) {
    __m256d vector = _mm256_loadu_pd(v + start_idx);
    __m256d base = _mm256_set_pd(2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i) {
        vector = _mm256_mul_pd(vector, base);
    }
    _mm256_storeu_pd(v + start_idx, vector);
}

void sub_func(double& item) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 128; ++k) {
        item *= 2.0;
    }
}

int main() {
    const size_t size = 8;
    double* v = new double[size];
    init(v, size);
    const int num_repeat = 2000;//I should repeat my measuraments 
                               //because I want to get average time - it is more clear information
    double total_time_sse = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < num_repeat; ++p) {
        init(v, size);
        TimerHc t;
        t.restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 8) {
            sub_func_sse(v, i);
        }
        total_time_sse += t.toc();
    }

    double total_time = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < num_repeat; ++p) {
        init(v, size);
        TimerHc t;
        t.restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            sub_func(v[i]);
        }
        total_time += t.toc();
    }
    std::cout << "time using sse = " << total_time_sse / num_repeat << std::endl <<
        "time without sse = " << total_time / num_repeat << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: 1) What is "performance"? 2) How do you compile your code (which flags do you use)? 3) If you use optimization, are you sure that `sub_func_sse` and `sub_func` are not optimized out? 4) Are you sure that `sub_func` is not vectorized by the compiler?

Comment: 1)Sorry, I wrote what is it performance for this task (performance = (time without sse) / (time using sse) ). 2) I compile my code with Microsoft visual studio in Release regime 3) I am not sure. I don't use some special optimizations flags for this. Maybe just Visual Studio used that, but I  just use Release 4)I am not sure. How can I check that?

Comment: For 3 and 4 you can look at the generated assembly code (in the debugger, for example).

Comment: Visual Studio will use SSE instructions for loops if it can. In general, if you write code that can be vectorized, the compiler will do so automatically. There's switches / pragmas to turn this off.

Comment: How can I switch that?

Comment: Are you sure your timer does what it should? 1. I can't see that m_stop is being used. 2. I can't see that toc() should even work in this context. Is there some code missing?

Comment: Side note: That doesn't meet my definition of 'performance', which would be a ratio between size of problem and duration. Increasing of *your* performance could also mean that performance (mine) of non-sse remains constant but sse performance gets worse – or even both get worse, but non-sse slower...

Comment: I fixed code .My code unfortunately is really big and here i just wanted to use only small part of my code. Now it should work, But I problem didn't solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I defined performance like (time without sse) / (time using sse).

What you measure is speedup.

The speedup you can expect from applying parallelizations is modelled by [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law). It relates the savings in those parts that can be made faster (by parallelization or other means) to the total speedup. Amdahl's law can be rather intimidating, because it basically says that making parts faster will not always gain you a total speedup. The limit in achievable speedup is determined by the relative fraction of the workload that can be parallelized.

[Gustavon's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustafson%27s_law) takes a different point of view. In a nutshell, it states that you just have to increase the workload to make efficient use of parallelization. More workload in total has typically less impact on overhead from parallelization and the non-parallel part of computations, hence (according to Amdahl's law) results in more efficient use of parallelism.

...and in some sense, that's what you are observing here. The bigger your array, the more impact parallelization has.

PS: This is just some handwaving to explain why the effect you see is not too surprising. Luckily there is another answer which addresses your specific benchmark in more detail.

Comment: Then in which case can I track the greatest positive impact of SSE instructions?(with wich size)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably a victim of [CPU frequency scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling); for stable results you should disable *dynamic frequency scaling* and *turbo boost*, or at least warm up the CPU before starting the measurement.

Since you start by measuring SSE performance and then proceed to regular performance, the CPU frequency is low in the beginning, so SSE performance appears worse.

Having said that, there are a few other issues with your approach:

- The overhead of `high_frequency_clock::now()` calls compared to the work being measured is high; move the time measurement to outside the `for (..num_repeat` loop, i.e. time the entire loop, not individual iterations (then optionally divide the measured time by the number of iterations).
- The results of the computation are never used; the compiler is free to optimize the work out entirely. Make sure to "use" the result, e.g. by printing it.
- It is quite inefficient to multiply a double by `2.0`. Indeed, the non-SSE version is optimized to an ADD instead (`item *= 2.0` ==> `vaddsd  xmm0, xmm0, xmm0`). So your hand-made SSE version is losing out.
- An optimizing compiler will probably auto-vectorize your non-SSE code. To be sure, always check the generated assembly. [Link to godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/-YeJZ5)
- Use a benchmarking framework like [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark); it will help you avoid many pitfalls associated with code benchmarking.

Comment: gcc/clang will optimize a multiply by `2.0` into an add same,same if it's profitable.  (ICC and MSCV don't optimize intrinsics). In this case mul might be *better*; it would have better throughput on Haswell/Broadwell (2/clock `vmulpd`, 1/clock `vaddpd`.) On Broadwell `vmulpd` even has the same latency as `vaddpd`, although mul is higher latency on Haswell. (On Skylake mul/add/fma all run on the same execution unit with the same perf). Mul would allow a memory-source load+multiply, maybe getting closer to the 1 store/clock limit. Add would avoid needing a vector constant of `set1(2.0)` though.

Comment: *Make sure to "use" the result, at least with casting it to void: (void)result.* Merely casting to void is not meaningful.  You have to use it as an input to something that can't optimize away, like assign to `volatile double sink = result`, or print it.

Comment: Oh, I looked more closely at this benchmark and it's multiplying *the same* value by `2.0` 128 times, creating a long loop-carried dep chain.  If that doesn't optimize at compile time into multiplying by a double with a huge exponent.  But probably not because repeated rounding at each step might not give identical results to one rounding.  But yes, higher `vmulpd` latency than `vaddpd` is a problem on CPUs before Skylake if the compiler doesn't optimize it to `vaddpd` anyway.